# Precise definition of limits question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

I am trying out the following precise definition of a limit but seemed to be stuck at the following step below:

Given that: 
\begin{align}
 \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L
\end{align}

The precise definition is expressed as follows:
\begin{align}
0<|x-a|< \delta
\end{align}
\begin{align}
|f(x)-L|< \epsilon
\end{align}
I wanted to show that following if:
\begin{align} 
\lim_{x \to9} \sqrt{x} = 3
\end{align}

Then prove using the precise limit definition that 
\begin{align}
\sqrt{9} = 3
\end{align}

I attempted to subsitute with the following:
\begin{align}
0<|x-9|<\delta
\end{align}
\begin{align}
|\sqrt{x}-3|<\epsilon
\end{align}

To make it look similar to the top one I changed the bottom to this form:
\begin{align}
|\frac{x-9}{\sqrt{x}+3}|<\epsilon
\end{align}

But now I am stuck as I can't express epsilon nor delta, any clues where to go from here?

Comment: I have no clue what is the Cauchy's definition, and I didn't even get how that relation between delta and epsilon. I'm pretty new to maths so I don't know much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

From $|x-9| < \delta$,

$$9-\delta<x<9+\delta$$

If we pick $\delta < 1$, then we can conclude that

$$8 < x< 10$$

Try  to obtain an upper bound of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+3}$

Edit:

$$\sqrt{8}< \sqrt{x} < \sqrt{10}$$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+3} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{8}+3}$$

Hence you might want to choose $\delta$ such that $\frac{\delta}{\sqrt{8}+3}< \epsilon$.

Comment: This may sound stupid but may I ask why should we pick delta to be less than one? Can it be any other value? May I ask what is an upper bound?

Comment: We have to pick $\delta$ that is small enough for things to work. An upper bound for a set is a number that is at least as big as every number in the set.

Comment: Remark: I realized that you do not understand the definition of limit yet. My personal advice is always go slower, do not rush to do the exercise. revise the definition of limit first might help, do you understand notation such as $\forall$ and $\exists$? you need them in the definition of the limit.

Comment: I do understand for all and there exists, but since I am self studying the definition of the limit do you have any advice on where I should go? Also thanks for helping me

Comment: The relationship between $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ in the definition of limit is as follows: whenever someone give you a positive $\epsilon$ (you do not know what is this $\epsilon$ in advance), can you always find $\delta$ such that for any point, $x \neq a$ that is not too far from $a$, that is $0<|x-a|<\delta$, it has to satisfy the condition $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$.

Comment: you might want to flip  a few pages of your book back and check the definition and try simpler exercises first to get used to the definition of limit.  here is a link to multiple exercises with solution for proving things using $\epsilon$ $\delta$ definition https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/preciselimdirectory/PreciseLimit.html

Comment: Alright thanks, I will mark this as answered in that case

Comment: Remark: you still have to verify if this $\delta$ really work, start form if $0<|x-9|<\delta$, where here is the $\delta$ that we have chosen, try to prove that $|f(x)-3|<\epsilon$.